# How to bind a custom static object to Null

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, data-binding

I have the following class:

```
public class UserInformation : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    private const string matchEmailPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$";

    public override string  ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + Surname;
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == null) return string.Empty;
            string result = string.Empty;

            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                        result = "Name cannot be empty.";
                    break;
                case "Surname":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname))
                        result = "Surname cannot be empty.";
                    break;
                case "Identifier":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Identifier))
                        result = "Identifier cannot be empty.";
                        break;
                case "Email":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
                        result = "Email cannot be empty.";
                    else
                    {

                        if (!Regex.IsMatch(Email, matchEmailPattern))
                            result = "Email format is invalid.";
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public string Error { get; private set; }
}
```

Notice that this is a validation class for WPF TextBoxes. In my `Resources`, I declare it as a static resource:

```
<custompackage:UserInformation x:Key="UserInformation" />
```

And I use it to validate some `TextBox`. That works fine. But whenever I want to use this attribute twice, it contains the values introduced the first time I use the static resource binding.

How can I empty this static resource object programmatically (I mean, when I decide to do so) so I can ensure next time I use it it will be null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the resource to be shared across its usage, set **[x:Shared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** to false on the resource. This will make sure that you will get new resource instance per its usage.

```
<custompackage:UserInformation x:Key="UserInformation"
                               x:Shared="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can derive from `MarkupExtension`:

```
public class UserInformation : MarkupExtension, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
// the rest of your Class
}
```

And then you don't need to declare it as a static resource you can simply use it like markup instead of {StaticResource xxx} you write {UserInformation} and because its a MarkupExtension it will instantiate a class and return it, solving you problem as its a new instance per usage.